# Is OpenKM have a BarCode module

Tags: barcode, openkm

My question divided to three questions:

1. is OpenKm accept Bar Code ??
2. if yes how can enter a bar Code to OpenKm DMS ??
3. how find something using bar code in dms

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Are you a aware that a barcode is just some kind of string encoding, and therefore can be represented as a string and a type of code?

Comment: yes that is true, but i want to know if OpenKM has feature which allow to search using barcode ?? i want to know that to know the benefits of barcode in DMS as general

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about OpenKM barcode reader at https://www.openkm.com/en/barcode.html also I suggest take a look at this video what might ilustrate the idea behing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=TkYS33I88oU

By default OpenKM comes with a barcode engine, but might integrate commercial solution into.

You can use the search engine to find a document with some barcode, query can be done to content or metadata.